# How to change the data store of a perviously created dojo grid?

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid

Within my on RowClick event handler I have to change the store like:

```
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: somedata});

thisObj.myGrid.store = store
```

but this does not work because some dojo internal assertion fails.

Answer (score 4):

I figured out my own solution:

```
var store = new ItemFileWriteStore({data: somedata});

thisObj.myGrid.store.close();
thisObj.myGrid.setStore(store);
```